# FreeIPA migrate the current NFSv4 storing home directories to another server

Tags: centos, redhat, nfs, kerberos, freeipa

I have a FreeIPA set-up that uses NFSv4 to store users' home directories. NFS is running on the same physical server as the FreeIPA. CentOS btw. I'd like to move the NFS server on a new machine and add more storage.

I have searched for documentation but there's no guide on how to perform this. Not much information on the internet either. Mb it's too trivial of a task and no one bothers to ask XD.

Clients get kerberos tickets to access their files.

If anyone has already done it or has an idea, could you please give me the steps to follow or things to try.

I thought of just copying data and spinning up a new NFS server on another machine but it's not obvious what I should update in FreeIPA config so that it plays together nicely.

Feel free to ask for additional information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, just copying thenfilws and spinning a new NFS server should be sufficient. You will need to add keytab file for the new server and configure sssd to use LDAP server running on FreeIPA to enforce krb5 authentication and proper user mapping. Anr of course ti updates mount option on the clients to use the new server.